# How to route with routeParams?

Tags: angularjs

Just trying to figure out routeParams with a simple exp:

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/routePerson/:personId', {
  templateUrl: 'person.html',
  controller: 'showCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: 'index.html'
      });
}]);

app.controller('showCtrl', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {

  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data){
      $scope.names = data;
     $scope.names_id = $routeParams.personId;
    });

});
```

As I click one of the link names I get all the names instead getting the name of selected object id.. How do I get the object name of the clicked object id?

To be more clear: http://plnkr.co/edit/c8z2IRzYcHKF6G8VmVoy?p=preview

Thnx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting correct ID. You just need to print it in your html.

```
<span>Person ID - {{names_id}}</span>
```

If you want name according to selected ID then do like below:

```
<span ng-repeat="t in names" ng-if="t.id == names_id"> {{t.name}} </span>
```

[To get name based on ID](http://plnkr.co/edit/CuqWJjD2ZFxjFHgbJWdI?p=preview)

[Updated Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/ORshGgxrOdGh3WnO34mw?p=preview)